# Should plugin-development also be discussed here?

Tags: discussion

Personally, I'd love to see plugin-development related questions over here. But I can also see the possibility, that to many of those questions could scare away non-technical visitors, if they start overwhelming the front-page.

Would do you guys think?

Comment: There are two tags which relate to plugins... We have [tag:plugin-dev] for learning how to write a plugin, and [tag:plugins] for more general questions about plugins, or if the author is unsure whether a plugin is required to solve their problem.

Comment: @LindseyD I'd like to propose 'plugin: PluginName' for discussions about specific plugins.

Comment: Very interesting, there may be some value in that. Here are my initial thoughts... (1) The syntax you propose would get "flattened" when the tag is saved. So "plugin: PluginName" would become the "pluginpluginname" tag. We could, however, create a standard syntax of **"plugin-pluginhandle"**. (2) I wonder how widely used those tags would be over time. To many novice SE users, they might just slap a "plugins" tag into their question and call it a day (despite the fact that they're inquiring about a specific plugin). (3) Overall, I like the idea, and I'd be down to move forward with it!

Comment: (1) Ah, didn't know it would be flattened, but I like your syntax. (2) Maybe it would be possible to add a 'Bulletin' to the sidebar or some kind of info to the 'new question' page. - If not, we can always start editing...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Absolutely! If someone were searching for information about Craft CMS development, I sure would like them to find *this* site.

If third-party plugins are an integral part of the Craft CMS landscape, then certainly **they should be on topic here.** As a matter of fact, the developers of these products and services tend to have communities of their own. You should actively embrace and *encourage* them become part of the ecosystem of *this* site.

We get a lot of requests from project teams about how they can use Stack Exchange to support their communities. I see no reason why this site couldn't provide fantastic technical support for these communities.

Comment: Totally agree. I’m not worried about it scaring off non-technical users, or plugin questions overrunning the site. Everyone at least understands that plugins play an important role, even if it’s not for them, and there will always be far more people with non-plugin-related questions.

Comment: I agree as well. Also if a non-technical user really doesn't want to see plugin questions they can always set some ignored tags to try to weed them out.

Answer (score 2):

I think they're appropriate and important to have here.

Comment: Having it all in one place seems like a win.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, I think plugin development questions are appropriate for this community.