# How do we want to handle "plugins" & "plugin-dev" tags?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, tags

Right now, "plugin-dev" is [the most-utilized tag for Stack Exchange questions](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/tags). We've [agreed that the topic is welcome on Stack Exchange](https://craftcms.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5/should-plugin-development-also-be-discussed-here), how to [tag specific plugins making them easy to follow](https://craftcms.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18/protocol-for-discussing-a-specific-plugin), and I think that we should account for the different types of plugin discussions that are bound to come up.

The issue of further differentiating **plugins vs. plugin *development*** questions was recently [brought up without much discussion](https://craftcms.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33/special-treatment-for-plugin-dev-tag). I also noticed that Brandon [suggested](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms) that the "plugins" tag should be a synonym for "plugin-dev", which would mean that there is *no* differentiation between the two.

I would argue that there are two types of plugin questions:

1. **General questions**, like "do I need a plugin to...?" or "do any plugins exist for...?" ([example](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/299/what-is-the-current-landscape-regarding-e-commerce-plugins-for-craft))
2. **Development questions**, like "how can I get my plugin to...?" or "why isn't my plugin functioning as I understand it should?" ([example](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/895/is-it-possible-to-use-the-elementtype-modal-ui-for-a-custom-field-type-plugin))

For this reason, I think it makes sense to keep a differentiation between the "plugins" and "plugin-dev" tags. As it's an important and complicated issue, I'd like to know what people think.

---

On a related note, I propose changing the name of **"plugin-dev" to "plugin-development"** so that it's more explicit. I'd love to hear what others think.

In summary:

- Are the existing "plugins" and "plugin-dev" tags perfect as-is?
- Does it make sense to rename "plugin-dev" to "plugin-development"?
- Are there any other plugin tagging issues we should be mindful of?

Comment: @LindseyD Wow, thanks for the edits! Any chance you'd like to edit everything I write?

Comment: I think that "plugin" and "plugin-dev" should be different and only "plugin-dev" should be used for development questions. I think "dev" is clear enough.

Comment: @MattStein Lol, hope I didn't get too carried away there! :)

Comment: @SimonKuran Thanks for the feedback. So ultimately, you're saying to leave everything as is?

Comment: @LindseyD Not at all, I genuinely appreciate it. You made me more organized and succinct.

Comment: @MattStein Then the system works! :)

Comment: @LindseyD Yes, I think so. The synonym by Brandon has only been proposed, it's not active right? The tag synonym page isn't very clear (if you sort by [suggested](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?filter=suggested&tab=newest) Brandon's doesn't show up). I definitely think "plugins" should be for plugin talk _not_ involving plugin development.

Comment: Yes, the synonym is just a proposal. (Apparently this is one of the things I can see now, so apologies if that was confusing.) He also said to ignore it in today's Craft chat, which means I should probably clear it out. I just wanted to solicit opinions first and make sure I'm not drunk on power. :)

Comment: @MattStein Ok, thanks. I could only see the synonym when I had the sort set to "all", which was a bit confusing, but I see you already got rid of it. ;) So I'm happy the way it is now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Are the existing "plugins" and "plugin-dev" tags perfect as-is?

At first I thought so, but now I'm not so sure. Currently, [plugin](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plugin) is being mostly used to talk about plugin *development* rather than questions about plugin *usage*. If that's really the purpose of the tag, then I think it should be merged with the more explicit [plugin-development](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plugin-development)

But we might actually need a general tag about plugin *usage*. If that's the case, then I think [plugin](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plugin) would work well for that.

> Does it make sense to rename "plugin-dev" to "plugin-development"?

Yes. I think [plugin-development](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plugin-development) is better than [plugin-dev](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plugin-dev) Why not be explicit? Especially since auto-suggest means that one won't have to type more than a few characters anyway.

[image: question tagging autosuggest]

Comment: Done, with [tag:plugin-development] being the primary tag for *building plugins*, [tag:plugins] for plugin availability and usage questions, and [tag:plugin-dev] as a lasting synonym.