# Special treatment for "plugin-dev" tag?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tags

Is it possible to style the "plugin-dev" tag differently to all the other tags, as an indicator to differentiate the question types.

I consider plugin development to be an "advanced" topic, with little interest to Craft newcomers. PHP knowledge isn't required to make a Craft site and those questions might evoke that'd be the case.

Speaking for me (has no advanced php skills / only one very rudimentary craft plugin) I often skim through the headlines of all the new questions to find sth. I could possibly contribute to. And I'd welcome a more apparent way to distinguish "user" from "plugin-dev" question, other then reading through the list of tags.

Comment: I can't speak to the *possibility* of this, but I'd be very interested to understand your rationale behind the thought.

Comment: Ditto @MattStein. I'm sure it's possible to color-code specific tags (though I haven't figured out how yet), I've seen it done with some existing specialty tags. But it begs the question, "why plugin-dev specifically?" You can easily set plugin-dev as one of your Favorite Tags in the sidebar.

Comment: Switch perspective to being a newcomer who what's to learn all the nice things about Craft but not plugin dev.

Comment: @LindseyD That came up [over here](http://meta.craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/32/are-plugin-design-questions-appropriate-for-this-site?lq=1) and I think it's to serve as a warning for visitors more than a convenient highlight. But I don't want to speak for Christian!

Comment: Yeah almost right except that I read your post after I had the idea, @Matt.

Comment: @ChristianSeelbach I see your point, and I also think that a newcomer could distinguish between approachable and overwhelming topics/tags. I'm confused by a whole lot on Stack Overflow, so I just pay attention to certain tags I'm comfortable with.

Comment: @ChristianSeelbach Just referencing for context, no offense intended!

Comment: All good @matt. Just wanted to point out that we two had something similar at the same time in mind. To do something with the Dev questions! :)

Comment: @Christian With this question, are you looking to see whether it's mechanically possible to highlight tags, or dive into the philosophical question of distinguishing between "layers" of Craft development?

Comment: The second! I've seen it that it is technically possible.

Comment: In that case, I'd love to see you make your case for distinguishing and see what others think. This is obviously important.

Comment: @matt it's actually both. It is possible but I don't know if we can do that while in beta or if a SE site can have individual tags treated besides some default SE 'attenton' tags.

Comment: @MattStein So? Reviewing? If so, please add [status-review]. If declined, add [status-declined]. Maybe you plan to do it, so [status-planned]. If you won't review this request in the near future, then [status-deferred].

Comment: @nicael Again, thanks for your input. I marked this deferred since the question could be improved, and I don't feel comfortable making a decision without more community input.

Comment: @ChristianSeelbach I'd love to see this question improved/clarified so people have a chance to react to both of your suggestions. I think it's a valid/important concern that could use more community input.

Comment: @matt I think I was too slow then...

Comment: @ChristianSeelbach Ha, I feel like I'm usually trying to keep up with *you*! Anyway I'd be interested in your perspective regardless of when you share it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've finally confirmed that it's not possible to manipulate the colors of tags. So to directly answer the question, **we don't have the ability to do that**.

The question implies that the topic of plugin development may have little or no value (or even be off-putting) to some visitors, which may be interesting in a separate question or discussion.

If that's the case, any Stack Exchange member can utilize [favorite and ignored tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19173/what-do-favorite-tags-and-ignored-tags-do) to call out or hide [certain tags](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/10/expressing-your-tag-preferences/).

In your case just add the "plugin-dev" tag to the ignore list:

[image: users preferences for tags]

and all questions tagged likewise will appear grayed out (or completely hidden) on the index pages:

[image: example view for grayed out questions]

Comment: First declined request. Congrats! :D Actually its possible to apply some special color for a tag.

Comment: @nicael Any citation would be helpful, for or against. I got my answer chatting with moderators, and will change my answer if it's wrong.

Comment: I didn't say that your answer is wrong :D For example all metas and [MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com) itself have tag coloring, which is done by CM. You can't do anything with coloring, I think ;-)

Comment: @nicael to me it sounds as if you are saying matt's answer is wrong.

Comment: @Christian How? Of course, it isn't. And I agree with Matt.

Comment: Thanks for bringing this up in the mods chat and getting this answer, Matt. Appreciated!

Comment: @ChristianSeelbach Happy to try and find an answer!

Comment: @nicael you simply put that counter-statement without further explanation. That's how.

Comment: Matt, tag preferences is an even better way to accomplish what I was after. Thanks!